# How to compute $\lim_{x\to{\pi/2}} \frac{\cos{x} }{\sqrt[3]{(1-\sin{x})^2}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim_{x\to{\pi/2}} \frac{\cos{x} }{\sqrt[3]{(1-\sin{x})^2}}$$

I am on terms with high school level calculus, and can solve this using L-hospital's method, but cannot come up with any other method to do the same. Please can someone tell me about any alternative methods to solve this question?

Comment: Just to confirm, is it supposed to be $(\sqrt[3]{1 - \sin x})^2$?

Comment: yes sir, it is supposed to be just that

Comment: In that case, the limit does not exist, so I don't know how you computed it with L.H.

Comment: im sorry sir, wrong question

Comment: kindly ignore this

Comment: Let $x=y+\frac \pi 2$ and work around $y=0$

Comment: Thankyou sir @ClaudeLeibovici

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a bit easier:

\begin{eqnarray*} \frac{\cos x}{\sqrt[3]{(1 - \sin{x})^2}}
& = & \sqrt[3]{(1 + \sin{x})^2} \frac{\cos x}{\sqrt[3]{\cos^4{x}}}\\
& = & \frac{\sqrt[3]{(1 + \sin{x})^2}}{\sqrt[3]{\cos x}}\\
& \stackrel{x \to (\frac{\pi}{2})^-}{\longrightarrow} & +\infty
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0):

Use standard trigonometrical formulae and write the function of the limit (setting $y=tan(\dfrac{x}{2}$))

$\dfrac{1-y^{2}}{1+y^{2}}$.$\dfrac{1}{(1-\dfrac{2y}{1+y^{2}})^{2/3}}$=

=$\dfrac{(1-y^{2})(1+y^{2})^{2/3}}{(1+y^{2})(1-y)^{4/3}}$

$=(1+y^{2})^{-1/3}\dfrac{1+y}{(1-y)^{1/3}}=f(y)$.

Since $y\to 1$   we clearly see that $\displaystyle \lim_{y \to 1^{+}}f(y)=-\infty$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{y \to 1^{-}}f(y)=+\infty$

therefore the limit does not exist!

Answer (score 0):

For $x \to (\frac{\pi}{2})^-$ we have $\cos x = (1 - \sin^2{x})^{1/2}$ and therefore:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to (\frac{\pi}{2})^-} \frac{\cos x}{\sqrt[3]{(1 - \sin{x})^2}} &= \lim_{x \to (\frac{\pi}{2})^-} \frac{(1 - \sin^2{x})^{1/2}}{(1 - \sin{x})^{2/3}}\\
&= \lim_{x \to (\frac{\pi}{2})^-} \frac{(1 - \sin{x})^{1/2} \times (1 + \sin{x})^{1/2}}{(1 - \sin{x})^{2/3}}\\
&= \lim_{x \to (\frac{\pi}{2})^-} \frac{(1 + \sin{x})^{1/2}}{(1 - \sin{x})^{1/6}}\\
&= +\infty
\end{align*}
But if $x \to (\frac{\pi}{2})^+$, then $\cos{x} = -(1 - \sin^2{x})^{1/2}$ and the same calculation shows that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to (\frac{\pi}{2})^+} \frac{\cos x}{\sqrt[3]{(1 - \sin{x})^2}} = -\infty
\end{align*}
So the given limit doesn't exist.

Comment: Thankyou  sir. ㅤ